# django - how to override admin templates

Tags: django-admin

I want to change the way the add new object page looks in the admin page.
I do not want to change the fields but want to arrange the inputs, for example 2 fields on the firt line, then some paragraph then two other fields.
I read about **add_form_template** and my guess is that this is supposed to allow me to change the template without defining the form.
Here is my attempt which does not show the fields:
Does anyone know whether I need to define the form and pass it in and how?
If I have to pass in the form, then what is add_form_template used for?

```
from settings import BASE_DIR
import os

@admin.register(Owner)
class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dealer/templates/add_owner.html')
    list_display = ('name', 'country', 'city', 'car')


@admin.register(Car)
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)

//----- add_owner.html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Owner</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Create</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: About your `add_form_template` - you must not use absolute paths for the templates. So you should have the template as file in `dealer/templates/dealer/add_owner_form.html` and use `dealer/add_owner_form.html` as `add_form_template`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the admin templates to customize your field's layout. Use [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) instead:

```
# admin.py
@admin.register(Owner)
class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
                ('name', 'country'),
                'city'
                )
        }),
        ('Another Fieldset', {
            'description': 'Some information to display...',
            'fields': (
                'car', 
            ),
        }),
    )
```

Comment: That's very useful. Although I'd like to know how to customize it to make it look exactly like a given complex form with specific fonts, colors, etc so I need to use my own template.

Comment: Also, this does not make them horizontal, it just groups them together vertically.

Comment: Are you using an additional admin library/skin/etc? With a default Django installation `name` and `country` would display horizontally aligned.

Comment: I think I did something wrong; now it's working. Thanks